# Angular 15: Cannot access 'x' before initialization

Tags: angular, angular15

I have decided I am lost on this issue. Everything on the internet says circular dependency, but I can't find one. It is complaining about a variable in our app.module, not another component.

Some background, this was added when we were on Angular 9 around January 2021 and has been there ever since. This is currently running in production with Angular 14, and is working as expected.

I followed this guide to do the upgrade, just as I did when I did 12=>13 and 13=>14.

https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=14.0-15.0

I guess I am concerned that this part is what is bothering me, but I didn't see anything for us to change.

[image: update injector]

Now I am upgrading to Angular 15, no code changes, and I am getting this error message at runtime during startup.

[image: console error]

If I click on the compiled main.js it shows that it compiles this way (which Angular 14 compiled the same way)

[image: compiled js]

Here is a trimmed down copy of our app.module. I removed some stuff I believe isn't relevant to make this more concise.

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER, ErrorHandler, Injector } from '@angular/core';

/** A angular injector that can be imported and used to get required services without needing to create a class constructor */
export let appInjector: Injector;

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initialization, deps: [EnvironmentApiService, AuthService, UserContextService, ToastService, SignalrHubService, RouterExtService, MonitoringService], multi: true },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthorizationInterceptor, multi: true },
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: UnhandledErrorHandler },
        { provide: 'WINDOW', useValue: window }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {

    public constructor(injector: Injector) {
        appInjector = injector;
    }

}
```

Then the appInjector is used in all of our services calling to our API backend, accountByAccountId.ts for example.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { lastValueFrom, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { appInjector } from '@/app.module';
import { createObservable } from '@/services/api/createObservable';

const http = appInjector.get(HttpClient);

function get(accountId: string): Promise<Readonly<AccountModel>> {
    return lastValueFrom(http.get<Readonly<AccountModel>>(`/api/account/${accountId}`)).then(acct => Object.freeze(acct));
}
```

I have commented out all the providers in app.module, hoping that would point at a problem, but there was no change.
I have even started a new project, in Angular 15, setting up the app.module, appInjector, and a single service the same way, and it all worked.

So, I don't understand what I am missing, or what changed, but I can't get my site to startup.